# How to show/hide only the specific div class from a php foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found similar questions here but due to my difficult design structure I am not sure how to implement that here. This is a post and comments like one in facebook. The whole post is created through the foreach loop. So there will be multiple posts with the same div class name. Within the post i have  classes namely postbox and commentbox. There is a div class box within the post box to show/hide comments section which i use as a button to click on.
So when user clicks on that it should show/hide only the comment section of that particular post. So in nutshell the one in grey is the button and the one in light green is the div class I want to show. The whole thing is in a for each loop.Can someone help me to achieve this through jQuery ?
That will be a great help. Thanks in advance.[image]

**Update**:- After reading some comments I realized that a unique div id is required So I made changes and added unique ids in the fooreach loop when I create them. I use the following jquery to get the selected id

```
$(function() {
  $('div').click(function() {
    displayBlock($(this).attr('class'));
    });
});
```

and I use this function to get the commentbtn_box class name. So I am hoping that using the next sibling of the parent of the commentbtn_box can solve my issue. But I dont know how to execute that though. Can anyone help me ? Thanks for your comments.

Comment: You should have a different class name for different posts, so you can get the specific post block. Ex. assign post id as a class name in each posts.

Comment: @Chinito, classes shouldnt be used for unique identification.. that is the purpose of the `id` attribute

Comment: @haxxxton then use `id` attribute :D

Comment: Okey now I understand. I think I should use different class names..probably with for loops I think. Otherwise it wont make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the Class name and the index of the class to get specific.

```
$(document).on('click', '.something', function(){
 $('.className:nth-child(1)').hide();
 $('.className:nth-child(2)').show();
});
```

Comment: Hey I have a quick question. I added unique ids but do you think if I call the parent's next sibling of my button class(commentbtn_box)  can help ? If so how to call the sibling of parent ?